# User session isn't being created, any idea why not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I'm using a customised devise sessions controller to manage my user sessions, however whenever I try sign in as an existing user, my log in functionality doesnt work, it just returns the sign in form, and the server returns this message:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-27 13:19:46 +0200
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lLtGottAklgEmCS2Y04FFZw3vAtd6EHkKOQMBCOJ4B6yeuFvN34j4OhYz9vd0SzW+gAwCI7GobMs20ubug24Fw==", "user"=>{"cell_number"=>"0798900606", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."cell_number" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["cell_number", "0798900606"]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lLtGottAklgEmCS2Y04FFZw3vAtd6EHkKOQMBCOJ4B6yeuFvN34j4OhYz9vd0SzW+gAwCI7GobMs20ubug24Fw==", "user"=>{"cell_number"=>"0798900606", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Rendered users/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/application (60.1ms)
Rendered application/_analytics.html.slim (4.7ms)
Rendered application/_environment_indicator.html.slim (2.5ms)
Rendered application/_preloader.html.slim (2.4ms)
Rendered application/_flashes.html.slim (3.7ms)
Category Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."uuid" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 746ms (Views: 660.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

My Sessions Controller looks like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
before_action :configure_sign_in_parameters

  def new
   super
  end

  def create
   @user = User.find_by(cell_number: params[:user][:cell_number])
  super
  end

  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   root_path
  end

  def configure_sign_in_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in).push(:cell_number, :password)
  end

end
```

My routes look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 ### Admin
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 ### User
 devise_for :users, controllers: { :registrations => "users/registrations",
                                :sessions => "users/sessions",
                                :passwords => "users/passwords" }

   devise_scope :user do
   namespace :vodacom do
     namespace :users do
       get "/register", to: 'registrations#new'
       get "/create", to: 'registrations#create'
     end
    end
  end
end
```

And my sign in form looks like this:

```
h2 Normal Log in

= simple_form_for @user, url: user_session_path(@user) do |f|
  div class="form-inputs"
    = f.input :cell_number, required: true, autofocus: true
    = f.input :password, required: true
    = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?

  div class="form-actions"
    = f.button :submit, "Log in"
```

Any clue what i'm doing wrong? My application controller specifies that a user should be authenticated before any action.

Comment: `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)` -- login failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, my user model does not have an email attribute, rather it has a cell_number attribute. So since i'm using devise, devise defaults "email" as the authentication key for the model. In order to fix this i had to specify cell_number as an authentication key in my User model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable,
       :registerable,
       :recoverable, 
       :rememberable,
       :registerable,
       :authentication_keys => [:cell_number]
```